# Suppose $(X,Y) \overset{d}{=} (X,Z)$ and $Y$ is $Z$-measurable. Prove $X$ and $Z$ conditionally independent given $Y$.

Tags: probability-theory

This is a question out of Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability.

Suppose $(X,Y) \overset{d}{=} (X,Z)$ and $Y$ is $Z$-measurable. Prove $X$ and $Z$ conditionally independent given $Y$.

I can show that $P(X \in B \mid Y) \overset{d}{=} P(X \in B \mid Z)$, but I'm having trouble showing a.s. equality. (I've been trying to show that $P(X \in B \mid Y)$ is a version of $P(X \in B \mid Z)$, but to no avail.)

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that showing $P(X \in B \mid Y) = P(X \in B \mid Z)$ a.s. is an equivalent condition by one of Doob's lemmas.

Comment: This is reminiscent of, but different from, certain excercises seen in statistics textbooks: Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\mathrm{i.i.d.}\ N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Show that the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $(X_1+\cdots+X_n,X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)$ does not depend on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\mathrm{i.i.d.}\ \mathrm{Gamma}$ with shape parameter $\alpha$ and scale parameter $\beta$.  Show that the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $(X_1+\cdots+X_n,X_1\cdots X_n)$ does not depend on $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: . . . so $Z$ would be in a role like that of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ in the problem in my comment above, and either of the two ordered pairs of random variables in the role of $X$.  You don't have equality of distributions, and the things denoted by Greek letters are not even random variables, but I still wonder if techniques applicatble to these statistics problems might be applicable to your problem.  But I'm not sure how to use the hypothesis of equality of distributions.

Comment: . . . or suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\mathrm{i.i.d.}\ \mathrm{Uniform}(0,\theta)$. Show that the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ does not depend on $\theta$. I add this one just to make clear that it's not only sums and products that can appear in this role. Nor is it always i.i.d. random variables: Suppose $X\sim \frac12 e^{-|x-\theta|}\,dx$ for $\theta\in\{\pm 1\}$. Let $T(X)=\begin{cases} X&\text{if }|X|\le 1,\\ X/|X|&\text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$ Show that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $T(X)$ does not depend on $\theta$.${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea how I would take that from specific distributions to the general case, though. My instinct is that since $(X,Y)$ is equal to $(X,Z)$ in distribution, $Z$ can't have any more information about $X$ than $Y$, even though, as per the previous question you answered, $\sigma(Z) \supset \sigma(Y)$.

Comment: Sometimes it's done by brute-force computation of conditional probabilities, but sometimes more sophisticated methods are used.  Maybe I'll be back shortly.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the professor helped me out in office hours. If this was burning a hole in your curiosity:

Invoking equivalence of distribution in the correct ways, we can show $P(X \in B \mid Y) \overset{d}{=} P(X \in B \mid Z)$. Treating $P(X \in B \mid Y) = E( P(X \in B \mid Z) \mid Y)$, it follows from this general fact: If $X \overset{d}{=} E(X \mid \mathcal{F})$, then $X = E(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ a.s. (This can be seen by considering $E( |X - E(X \mid \mathcal{F})|^2 )$.